# Почему трисоляриане не смоделировали движение своих звезд?

Tags: физика, моделирование

Посмотрел сериал задача трех тел.

Посмотрел на википедии мол решения в виде простой формулы не существует, однако можно просто смоделировать, если условно каждую нано секунду вычислять воздействие всех сил и складывать их между собой.

И на сколько я понял текущие компьютеры могли бы рассчитать на сотню лет вперед без особо больших погрешностей траектории трех тел? или это не так?

Comment: "...в общем случае задача не имеет решения в виде конечных аналитических (!) выражений...".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Численное решение возможно, но оно неустойчиво относительно исходных данных. Малое изменение начальных позиций и скоростей приводит к большому изменению этих значений через некоторое время.

Например, запустим параллельно две симуляции. Во второй симуляции изменим скорость одной звезды на один сантиметр в секунду и будем следить как отличаются решения. Мы обнаружим что различие в скоростях и позициях накапливается определённым образом. А именно, скажем через неделю, различие в скоростях удваивается. Ещё через неделю различие ещё удваивается и так далее. Через 52 недели (год) разница между симуляциями составит до *2<sup>52</sup>* сантиметров в секунду. Разница так огромна, что две системы в ваших симуляциях двигаются совершенно различным образом.

Такое лавинообразное (экспоненциальное) накопление разницы не связано с ошибками округления при расчётах. Это свойство самой физической системы когда три звезды сравнимой массы связаны тяготением.

На самом деле, разница в скоростях не достигнет таких огромных величин - есть физические ограничения. Но главное что нужно понимать - если даже если вы умеете мерить скорости звёзд до сантиметра в секунду, вы не знаете что будет с системой через год.

Следующее соображение: пусть вы составили прогноз с приемлемой точностью на двадцать недель. Как нужно уточнить измерения, чтобы прогноз стал точным на двадцать одну неделю? Нужно измерить все параметры в два раза точнее. Каждая новая неделя в прогнозе обходится вам в удвоение точности исходных скоростей и положений.

Да вы можете взять мощный компьютер и вычислить траектории на год вперёд очень точно, вы просто не в состоянии измерить исходные параметры с достаточной точностью.

Похожие системы - [двойной маятник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), прогноз погоды. В всех случаях даже очень точное знание начальных условий через некоторое время превращается в полное неведение относительно состояния системы. Почитайте про [теорию хаоса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0).

Comment: Блин, а тут-то за что минусы?

Comment: В астрономии еще хорошо, можно не учитывать, что сам процесс измерения меняет состояние системы....

Comment: И это только в теории для известных тел (допустим, трех солнц) в гомогенной среде. Ошибка также растет из-за неизвестных/неучтенных тел и сил (планеты, астероиды, пылевые облака, соседние звезды, сама галактика, итп).

Comment: Ключевое здесь сказано в ответе Станислава: "малое изменени НАЧАЛЬНЫХ ПОЗИЦИЙ", т.е. это уже не решение в общем виде, мы моделируем исходя из определенных начальных условий. а общее решение сделать таким образом не выйдет.